# Fetching Data from MySQL and Inserting it in MS SQL SERVER in visual studio c#

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, .net

Am trying to read a table from a Mysql database and store all of it in a ms sql server in c# am reading from mysql correctly  my problem is how to store the data i read in ms sql in the second part of code 
           string constring= ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cnxMysql"].ConnectionString;

```
        MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(constring);

        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM i_evt WHERE Updt=0",conn);

        conn.Open();


        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();




        string constring2 = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cnxsql"].ConnectionString;

        SqlConnection conn2 = new SqlConnection(constring2);

        SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO i_evt",conn2);

        conn2.Open();




        cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();

        conn2.Close();
        conn.Close();
```

Comment: You have written `INSERT INTO i_evt` but what? values/select clause missing.

Comment: your command text for cmd2 isn't complete as @Nilay said, you would need to pass values.

Comment: Yes read what i said , am stuck there i don't know how to get the data i read from mysql into the ms sql  that's where the data should go

Answer (score 0):

I have a reverse issue, I have to transfer data from MS SQL Server to MySQL. 
I have used below snippet for this, but I **personally don't recommend** this for production as it adds data one by one row. But you can use it for a small dataset or local environment. You can add a try-catch as well as customize as per your need. This is for just reference.

```
public void Main()
{
    var table = GetDataTableFromSQLServer();
    AddToMySQL(table);
}

private DataTable GetDataTableFromSQLServer()
{
    var connection = GetSqlServerConnection();
    string query = "SELECT Column1, Column2 FROM TableName WHERE Column3 is NOT NULL";

    var command = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
    connection.Open();
    var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    table.Load(reader);
    connection.Close();

    return table;
}

private void AddToMySQL(DataTable table)
{
    var connection = GetMySQLConnection();
    connection.Open();
    string query = "INSERT INTO TableName (column1, column2) VALUES(@column1, @column2);";

    int i = 0;
    foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
    {
        if (i % 1000 == 0)
        {
            // Closing & Reopening connection after 1000 records
            connection.Close();
            connection.Open();
        }

        Console.WriteLine($"Adding ({++i}/{table.Rows.Count})");

        MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
        command.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@column1", MySqlDbType.Int64) { Value = row.Field<long>("column1").Trim() });
        command.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@column2", MySqlDbType.VarChar) { Value = row.Field<string>("column2").Trim() });

        var affectedRows = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }

    connection.Close();
}

private SqlConnection GetSqlServerConnection()
{
    string connectionString = @"Data Source=...";
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    return connection;
}

private MySqlConnection GetMySQLConnection()
{
    MySqlConnectionStringBuilder connectionBuilder = new MySqlConnectionStringBuilder
    {
        Server = "...",
        Database = "...",
        UserID = "...",
        Password = "...",
        Port = 3306
    };

    MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionBuilder.ToString());
    return connection;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer below code, you can optimize this code as there is alot of space for optimization but this is simple for beginner to understand basic level:

```
MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(constring);
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM i_evt WHERE Updt=0", conn);
conn.Open();
DataSet data;
using (MySqlDataAdapter sqlAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(mySqlCommand))
    {
        data = new DataSet();
        sqlAdapter.Fill(data);
    }

string constring2 = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cnxsql"].ConnectionString;
SqlConnection conn2 = new SqlConnection(constring2);
conn2.Open();
for (int i = 0; i < data.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO i_evt(column1,column2) values(@col1,@col1)", conn2);
        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("col1", data.Tables[0].Rows[i][0].ToString());
        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("col12", data.Tables[0].Rows[i][1].ToString());
        cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
conn2.Close();
conn.Close();
```

Comment: Are you doing it for learning purpose or this is your assignment ..there are another way to do this